# How to change computer name windows server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I took domain controller from "'oldpc' with windowserver 2008" to "'newpc' windows server 2012 r2". I changed "oldpc" name succesfully. Then I tried to change "newpc" name to previously 'oldpc' name , it goes error: "Cannot create a file when that already exists."
But its pc name doesn't exist I changed "oldpc" name already. 
How can I find above existed "pcname" and delete it?

Comment: Have you manually updated the File Replication Service or Distributed File System Replication member object, as [described here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/90f461b1-46c6-42e3-b1fe-712258bd31fb/renaming-a-domain-controller?forum=winserverDS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you need to delete the 'oldpc' from the AD, and delete the DNS record. Just to be sure, run `ipconfig /flushDNS`. Also, when removing, make sure that the change is replicated to another DC (if you have any).